# VK api wall.get

Tags: vkontakte-api, get

Помогите пжл, я хочу передать информацию со стены группы на клиент. Использую
webView.loadUrl("https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/wall.get?owner_id=-XXXXXXX");

Как говорится в документации, ответ будет выводиться в формате JSON. А как сделать так, чтобы выводились все картинки и т.д. (в привычном нам графическом оформлении вконтакте) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ручками :) По-другому никак.
Берешь ответ, полученный сервером, преобразуешь в объект (например JSON.parse если это JS, json_decode если это PHP), затем для каждого сообщения на стене выдергиваешь параметры text, attachments и так далее. Если возникнут проблемы - задавайте вопросы, но уже более конкретнее, с примерами своего когда.